# How to call activity onDestroy() onBackPressed in android?

Tags: android

I have an app that contains a Login Activity , which is shown to the user when the app starts up,the issue is that the app closes without  getting a callback to OnDestroy() on back button press

code:-

```
private long lastPressTime = 1;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lastPressTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11905808/3022836)

Comment: Well of course not, you are quitting the whole process with System.exit(). Life cycle events do not trigger beyond that. You could try to replace System.exit() with finish(). But since I don't know what your app is supposed to do this might not help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `finish()` instead `System.exit(0)`,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
        System.exit(0);//
    onDestroy();  // but you can use finish(); here Destroy will be called
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lastPressTime = currentTime;    
    }
}
```